# how to read a socket packet properly

Tags: java

I have a server built in Java which listen at a specific port for incoming connection. But when I read lines of a packet it just get stuck.

Here is the portion of my code which read packet data:

```
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
System.out.println("Received Request!");
String MESSAGE = null;
Stream<String> ReadPacket = null;

try {
    dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
} catch(Exception ie) {
    System.out.println("Cound'nt create dOut");
}

try {
    IR = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
} catch(Exception ie) {
    System.out.println("Cound'nt create IR");
}

BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
System.out.println("Received Request!");
String MESSAGE = null;
Stream<String> ReadPacket = null;

try {
    ReadPacket = BR.lines();
} catch(Exception ie) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't Receive Message");
}

Object[] arr = ReadPacket.toArray();
MESSAGE = arr[0].toString();
System.out.println(MESSAGE);
```

As you can see it reads lines of a packet and then converts it to `String`, but it stuck in loop and never print me `MESSAGE`. Until I close my tab that I request from it goes out of loop.

Comment: I might need to see more code.  It looks like you're buffering a stream only to stream the buffer... The stream returned by `BR.lines()` is lazily populated.  Try doing an eager read from your InputStream and I'm guessing you'll start to see results.

Comment: Also, for the sake of instruction, you're not actually reading packets.  The reading and writing of physical packets is handled in the TCP layer, not in your java code.

Comment: before i was using readLine(), but that just reads one line not the hole packet data so i had to change it into lines that i could have access to the full data being sent.

Comment: the request is being made by the browser, it is an http request, my server replies to http requests

Comment: no as i shown you my server side code, then i just type 127.0.0.1:80 and the request is being made by the browser, just that

Comment: and the browser stuck in loading too, and says waiting for 127.0.0.1

Comment: You are reading an HTTP *request*, not a 'packet', and it has a syntax which you have made no attempt to implement. You need a good knowledge of both networking and RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP. I suggest you start the reading now.

Comment: my bad, i meant the packet data, sorry, so do you have any idea for what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you have a logic SNAFU here.  You have a buffered reader wrapped around a socket input stream.  The stream won't terminate until the socket is closed.  You won't get any response from the buffered reader in this case until the stream is terminated.  In fact, even if you used the readLine() method in a loop, it would only return if there happened to be a newLine character passed through the stream.  I think you need to rethink how you are consuming the socket input stream.

Comment: i just found that it stuck at the last line and where there is no newline, 
     if((MESSAGE.contains("/n")) != true){
      System.out.println(MESSAGE);
     }
     and the result is: Received Request!
1. GET / HTTP/1.1
2. Host: 127.0.0.1
3. User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:48.0)  4.Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
5.Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
6.Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
7.Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
8.Connection: keep-alive
9.Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
10.
11.       line 11 is where the program stucks